# Python not working properly on VM Guest Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: python, virtualbox

I have a Oracle Virtualbox VM 5.2.22 running Ubuntu 18.04 from a windows 10 machine.

On my computer everything is working fine. The same .vdi file with the same Virtualbox settings on a friends computer has something very strange happening.

If I get a python console from the home dir, it functions fine.

If I get a python console from a subdir, it fails on the command:

```
import logging
File "logging.py", line 5, in <module>
   import logging.handlers
ImportError: No module named handlers
```

which is odd as python is working and logging is in the standard library.

Two questions:

1) Why would one virtual machine be different than another in this regard? This machine was created using a clone without snapshots, the cloned version works fine on my machine.

2) Why the problem with python not being able to import part of the standard library?

I am assuming that the python problem is a symptom of a problem with the Virtual machine. As far as I can tell all of the VM options are identical.

Comment: Try running in an empty directory, in case you have developed a module/script of your own that clashes with the name of a Python module.

Comment: That is an excellent point, I will try that now. Thank you